# How do I make a puzzle piece mesh solid?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I created a rough puzzle piece in blender so I can export a .fbx and then import into Unity to create a virtual reality puzzle but when I import it into unity there are pieces of the mesh missing but in blender everything is solid.

After I create my mesh what is the best way to make the entire mesh solid so that when I import it there aren't missing pieces. I've tried flipping the normals and smart UV unwrapping but it doesn't help much.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please add some screenshots of the issue to have a visual representation of what the problem is. The more info, the better to help you

Comment: I think this might be a culling issue. Try turning off culling in the object's shader in Unity (cull off), and if that still isn't working, try looking into what is the best frontface/backface culling setup in blender for export to Unity.

Comment: UV unwrapping does nothing to the geometry. It just influences how textures are mapped onto the geometry. Please do add screenshots PS don’t use Imgur, just embed them directly into the question

Answer (score 0):

I selected one of the parts that were missing and chose *Normals > Recalculate Outside* and then chose *Shade Flat* and everything cleared up.

I will look into culling though I'll be making several puzzle pieces and the quickest solution is desired.[image: puzzle piece in blender]

Comment: The polygons might also need to be converted to triangles, as Unity is a game-engine.

This can be done with the triangulate modifier.